# Probability uniform distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If X is distributes uniform continuous - $X∼U(−1,3)$, and  W=$|X−1|$. 
I need to find $P(W≤0.45)$.

So I'm wondering how to do it with the absolute value? I started to use the Cumulative formula - $(x-a)/(b-a)$ and also not sure how the $W$ should be calculated here.

Comment: Will this help? $$P(W\leq 0.45)=P(|X-1|\leq 0.45)=
P(-0.45\leq X-1\leq 0.45)=
P(1-0.45\leq X\leq 0.45+1)$$

Comment: Thanks! so now all I did was to calculate $Xmax$ by $(1.45+1)/(3+1) = 0.6125$. Can I please ask If I'm in the right way?

Comment: **Hint:** $$P(W\leq 0.45)=P(|X-1|\leq 0.45)=
P(-0.45\leq X-1\leq 0.45)=\\
P(1-0.45\leq X\leq 0.45+1)=
P(0.55\leq X\leq 1.45)=\frac{1.45-0.55}{3-(-1)}=\frac{0.9}{4}$$

Comment: Can I ask why it's $0.55$ in the numerator? since In the formula it's $a$ from the uniform distribution, meaning $(-1)$

Comment: Well, you have the answer below ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you surely know, your $CDF_X$ is the following

$F_X(x)=\frac{x+1}{4}$

More precisely it is

$F_X(x)=\frac{x+1}{4}\mathbb{1}_{(-1;3)}(x)+\mathbb{1}_{[3;+\infty)}(x)$

so you probability is

$P[W \leq 0.45]=F_X(1.45)-F_x(0.55)=\frac{1.45+1}{4}-\frac{0.55+1}{4}=0.225$